# Column 'created_at' not imported

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, import, sorting, product-sorting

My goal is to sort products on the frontend from newest to oldest.

The products CSV file contains the `created_at` column (e.g. `2020-10-31 14:05:44`). Format seems to be correct.

After the standard import, I'm looking in the `catalog_product_entity` table, and `created_at` is actually the import's timestamp (e.g. `2020-11-28 17:38:48`).

Am I looking at the wrong DB field? Is there some locale-specific formatting under the hood? (I'm importing for the `ro` store)

*References*

- [The Complete Guide to Magento 2 Product Import / Export](https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-magento-2-product-import-export.html)
- [Importing system attribute "created_at" with a timestamp](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Importing-system-attribute-quot-created-at-quot-with-a-timestamp/td-p/433629)
- [date issues in magento 2.3.3](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/date-issues-in-magento-2-3-3/td-p/397573)

*Versions: Magento 2.3.5-p1, PHP 7.3.24*

Answer (score 0):

to check if you are looking at wrong DB check env.php under app/etc/ , how do you manage import?